# How to explode string into array with index in php?

Tags: php

I have a PHP string separated by characters like this :

```
$str = "var1,'Hello'|var2,'World'|";
```

I use explode function and split my string in array like this :

```
$sub_str = explode("|", $str);
```

and it returns:

```
$substr[0] = "var1,'hello'";
$substr[1] = "var2,'world'";
```

Is there any way to explode `$substr` in array with this condition:
first part of `$substr` is array index and second part of `$substr` is variable?

example :

```
$new_substr = array();
$new_substr["var1"] = 'hello';
$new_substr["var2"] = 'world';
```

and when I called my `$new_substr` it return just result ?

example :

```
echo $new_substr["var1"];
```

and return : hello

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

```
$str = "var1,'Hello'|var2,'World'|";
$sub_str = explode("|", $str);
$array = [];
foreach ($sub_str as $string) {
   $data = explode(',', $string);
   if(isset($data[0]) && !empty($data[0])){
     $array[$data[0]] = $data[1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to extract the keys and values, then using [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to put them together:

```
$str = "var1,'Hello'|var2,'World'|";
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\|)([^,]+),([^\|]+(?=\||$))/', $str, $matches);
$new_substr = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
print_r($new_substr);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [var1] => 'Hello'
  [var2] => 'World' 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/1iEk9)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `explode()`, `str_replace()` functions.

The Steps are simple:

1) Split the string into two segments with `|`, this will form an array with two elements.

2) Loop over the splitted array.

3) Replace single quotes as not required.

4) Replace the foreach current element with comma (,)

5) Now, we have keys and values separated.

6) Append it to an array.

7) Enjoy!!!

Code:

```
<?php
$string = "var1,'Hello'|var2,'World'|";
$finalArray = array();
$asArr = explode('|', $string );
$find = ["'",];
$replace = [''];
foreach( $asArr as $val ){
 $val = str_replace($find, $replace, $val);
  $tmp = explode( ',', $val );
  if (! empty($tmp[0]) && ! empty($tmp[1])) {
   $finalArray[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];
  }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($finalArray);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [var1] => Hello
    [var2] => World
)
```

[See it live:](https://3v4l.org/i7OWu)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$str = "var1,'Hello'|var2,'World'|";
$sub_str = explode("|", $str);
$new_str = array();
foreach ( $sub_str as $row ) {
  $test_str = explode( ',', $row );
  if ( 2 == count( $test_str ) ) {
    $new_str[$test_str[0]] = str_replace("'", "", $test_str[1] );
  }
}
print $new_str['var1'] . ' ' . $new_str['var2'];
```

Just exploding your `$sub_str` with the comma in a loop and replacing single quote from the value to provide the expected result.